# Incorrect value if interaction with filter (Date Slicer) is on

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

[here we can see the first table that has interaction with filters on top has wrong values but the second one when i turn the interactions off has right values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0xOe.png)

Here is my measure to calculate last year value

```
` Last_Year_value = CALCULATE(
    SUM(Profit_and_Loss[Value]),
    DATEADD('Calendar'[Date],-12,MONTH)
    )`
```

I have a relation one sided between profit_and_loss table and Calendare table
[here it is the relation between the two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zX51.png)

I tried using "REMOVEFILTERS() / ALL() / ALLEXCEPT()", but non of them worked.